# how to take the content of a file in nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a txt file and get the content in to a nested dictionary. Content of the file is as below.

```
Name: John Doe
Email: john.doe@exabeam.com

Name: Martina jackson
Email: Martina.jackson@exabeam.com

Name: Steve Bob
Email: steve.bob@exabeam.com

Name: John Doe
Email: john.doe@exabeam.com

Name: Steve Bob
Email: steve.bob@exabeam.com

Name: John Doe
Email: john.doe@exabeam.com
```

My purpose is to sort the file content in such a way that "name" should be the key and for every "name" how many times the email is mentioned should be in the nested dict as a value. Below is the sample output:

```
{ "John Doe": {"John.doe@exabeam.com": 3}, "Steve Bob": {"steve.bob@exabeam.com": 2}, "Martina Jackson":{"martina.jackson": 1}}
```

So, I tried something as below. But it's not working.

```
with open('contacts', 'r') as file:
    for read_file in file:
        new_dict = sorted(read_file.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['point'],reverse=True)
        print(new_dict)
```

When I execute the above program, I get below errors:

```
 new_dict = sorted(read_file.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['point'],reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you,

Comment: Based on your input file structure your error should be 'string' object has no attribute 'items' and not tuple. Can you confirm the input again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?

```
result = {}

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
    for name_line, address_line in zip(lines[::3], lines[1::3]):
        name = name_line.replace(": ", ":").split(":")[1].strip()
        address = address_line.replace(": ", ":").split(":")[1].strip()

        if not name in result:
            result[name] = {address: 1}
        else:
            result[name][address] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another example!

```
with open('contacts', 'r') as file:
    for read_file in file.read().split("\n\n"): #data chunks apart
        data = read_file.split("\n") #split email/name
        name = data[0].split(" ")[1] #split at space and grab second
        email = data[1].split(" ")[1] #^
        if name not in d:
            d[name] = {email:1}
        else:
            d[name][email] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```py
contacts = {}
with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as f:
  name = None

  for line in f:
    parts = line.rstrip().split(': ')

    if parts[0] == 'Name':
      name = parts[1]

      if name not in contacts:
        contacts[name] = {} # Initialize empty dict for new name

    elif parts[0] == 'Email':
      email = parts[1]

      if email not in contacts[name]:
        contacts[name][email] = 0 # Initialize count for new email

      contacts[name][email] += 1

print(contacts) # Outputs: {'John Doe': {'john.doe@exabeam.com': 3}, 'Martina jackson': {'Martina.jackson@exabeam.com': 1}, 'Steve Bob': {'steve.bob@exabeam.com': 2}}
```

Comment: In this way, each people's name has a space at first. For prevent it, we have to replace ": " to ":"(no space).

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand WHY such a data structure is advantageous,

```py
{"name":(email, count)}
```

would likely be better, as I only see one `email` per `name`.

But this parses the data into the format you specify:

```py
result = dict()

with open('contacts', 'r') as file:
    # read all lines from file
    lines = file.readlines()

    # process them in chunks
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
        name, email, _ = lines[i:i+3]

        # remove "NAME:" and "EMAIL:" aswell as newlines
        name = name.split(":")[1].strip()
        email = email.split(":")[1].strip()

        # If we haven't seen this name before, initialize dict
        if name not in result:
            result[name] = dict()

        # increment the number of times the email has been seen, else set to 1
        result[name][email] = result[name].get(email,0) + 1

print(result)
```

prints, as expected

```
{'John Doe': {'john.doe@exabeam.com': 3}, 'Martina jackson': {'Martina.jackson@exabeam.com': 1}, 'Steve Bob': {'steve.bob@exabeam.com': 2}}
```